# category with a designated period-2 contravariant functor

Tags: ct.category-theory

I'm working with a type of category C that is equipped with a designated period-2 contravariant functor $*\colon C\to C$. So: if $x\colon a\to b$ is a morphism then so is $x^*\colon b^*\to a^*$. And for composable morphisms $(ab)^*=b^*a^*$. And for objects and morphisms $(x^*)^*=x$. Does this have a name? Where is it studied? All I find in online search is dagger categories, which also require $*$ to be the identity on objects. In my application this is an unnatural requirement.

Similarly, I'm interested in quivers with a designated period-2 antiautomorphism $*$. These generate the kind of category described above in much the same way that a quiver generates a graph category. Anyone come across these? Again, all I find online is mention of dagger graphs, in which it is required that $v^*=v$ for vertices.

In the privacy of my home I've been calling these $*$-graphs and $*$-categories, but would love to know if they are already named. And where they have come up.